# Что происходит при истечении SO_KEEPALIVE?

Tags: c++, c, tcp

Что происходит c TCP-соединением при истечении таймаута `SO_KEEPALIVE`?

```
on = 1;
::setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &on, 1);
```

В документации сказано только то, что по истечению посылается SIGPIPE.

Что происходит с самим соединением? Закрывается ли при этом сокет?

Upd: Речь про Linux

Comment: msdn читали? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee470551(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С точки зрения программиста ситуация после истечения таймаута и отсутствия ответа или неудовлетворительности оного обрабатывается практически также как и корректное закрытие TCP соединения клиентом:

- Соединение закрывается, но дескриптор сокета — нет.
- `poll`/`select` возвращают сокет как готовый для чтения
- `read`/`recv` из оного возвращают ошибку (если верить Стивенсу, процитированному выше, то `errno` устанавливается в одно из значений `ETIMEDOUT`, `ECONNRESET`, `EHOSTUNREACH`).
- `write`/`send` приведут к посылке сигнала `SIGPIPE` и/или возврату ошибки (дабы не соврать не буду утверждать какой именно)

Answer (score 3):

Это выдержка из книги "Unix. Разработка сетевых приложений.(Стивенс)". В ней описано почти Всё.

Когда параметр SO_KEEPALIVE установлен для сокета TCP и в течение двух часов не происходит обмена данными по сокету в любом направлении, TCP автоматически посылает собеседнику проверочное сообщение (keepalive probe). Это сообщение — сегмент TCP, на который собеседник должен ответить. Далее события могут развиваться по одному из трех сценариев.

1. Собеседник отвечает, присылая ожидаемый сегмент ACK. Приложение не получает
   уведомления (поскольку все в порядке). TCP снова отправит одно проверочное сообщение еще
   через два часа отсутствия активности в этом соединении.
2. Собеседник отвечает, присылая сегмент RST, который сообщает локальному TCP, что
   узел собеседника вышел из строя и перезагрузился. Ошибка сокета, требующая обработки,
   устанавливается равной ECONNRESET и сокет закрывается.
3. На проверочное сообщение не приходит ответ от собеседника. Код TCP, происходящий от
   Беркли, отправляет восемь дополнительных проверочных сообщений с интервалом в 75 с,пытаясь выявить ошибку. TCP прекратит попытки, если ответа не последует в течение 11 мин и15 с после отправки первого сообщения.

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ

HP-UX обрабатывает поверочные сообщения так же, как и обычные данные, то
есть второе сообщение отсылается по истечении периода повторной передачи, после чего для каждого последующего пакета интервал ожидания удваивается, пока не будет достигнут максимальный интервал (по умолчанию — 10 мин).

Если на все проверочные сообщения TCP не приходит ответа, то ошибка сокета, требующая обработки, устанавливается в ETIMEDOUTи сокет **закрывается**. Но если сокет получает ошибку ICMP (Internet Control Message Protocol — протокол управляющих сообщений Интернета) в ответ на одно из проверочных сообщений, то возвращается одна из соответствующих ошибок, но сокет также **закрывается**. Типичная ошибка ICMP в этом сценарии — Host unreachable(Узел недоступен) — указывает на то, что узел собеседника не вышел из строя, а только является недоступным. При этом ошибка, ожидающая обработки, устанавливается в EHOSTUNREACH. Это может произойти из-за отказа сети или при выходе удаленного узла из строя и обнаружении этого последним маршрутизатором.